# shell tee not redirecting all command output to file

Tags: shell, pipe, tee

I'm running a command that output some lines of code during execution and some final ones when finished, but piping it to `tee` to have that output duplicated to file write just the final lines.

The command is `sam build`, and typical ouput is as follows, but only the last section (the result recap) is written to file.

##### Typical command output

```
sh-4.2# sam build | tee build.txt
Building codeuri: /var/task/lambda-functions/scaffold-site-codebase runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: ScaffoldSiteCodebaseFunction
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CleanUpNpmrc
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp
Building codeuri: /var/task/lambda-functions/confirm-new-purchase runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: ConfirmNewPurchaseFunction
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CleanUpNpmrc
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp
Building codeuri: /var/task/lambda-functions/register-new-customer runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: RegisterNewCustomerFunction
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CleanUpNpmrc
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp
Building codeuri: /var/task/lambda-functions/send-new-purchase-emails runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: SendNewPurchaseEmailsFunction
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CleanUpNpmrc
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp
Building codeuri: /var/task/lambda-functions/send-failed-subscription-renewal-email runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: SendFailedSubscriptionRenewalEmailFunction
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CleanUpNpmrc
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp
Building codeuri: /var/task/lambda-functions/create-stripe-customer runtime: nodejs18.x metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: CreateStripeCustomerFunction
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmPack
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopyNpmrcAndLockfile
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:CleanUpNpmrc
Running NodejsNpmBuilder:LockfileCleanUp

Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam/build
Built Template   : .aws-sam/build/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Validate SAM template: sam validate
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: sam sync --stack-name {{stack-name}} --watch
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided
```

##### file content

```
Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam/build
Built Template   : .aws-sam/build/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Validate SAM template: sam validate
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: sam sync --stack-name {{stack-name}} --watch
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided
```

Comment: Try capturing `stderr` too with `sam build 2>&1 | tee build.txt`

Comment: @MarkSetchell you're right, the building output is in `stderror`, cannot understand why, it is heavily illogical to me (maybe it is due `stdout` being buffered while `stderror` being not, but that's a whole another story).  
If you provide a formal answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass both `stderr` and `stdout` from `sam build` to `tee` like this:

```
sam build 2>&1 | tee build.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `stderr` to be piped to `tee` then you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` before the pipe.... `command foo 2>&1 | tee foo.txt`. `2>` represents directing `stderr` to `&1` `stdout`